# Rails button that can increment db data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a button that when clicked will add a value to the database and can increment.

I would prefer to use radio buttons, currently I have it set and when the radio button is selected, and the submit button is pressed it sets the value to the db. IT does not increment.

The code sample below is on the request#show page.  The goal is for a user to view the request, and if they can help they will select the radio button and hit submit and the data is incremented and saved into the db.

Example:

```
<%= simple_form_for @request do |f| %>

<%= f.radio_button :done, 1 %>I am helping<br/><br/>
<%= f.radio_button :done, 0 %>Maybe next time<br/><br/>

<%= f.button :submit %>
```

Below is my attempt at incrementing via the controller, but I am not sure how to call it when clicking submit:

```
  def incr_done
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])

    if @request.done == "yes" 
        then @request.done += 1
    else @request.done == "no"
         @request.done -= 1
    end
end

def done_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:done)
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users
get 'static_pages/home'

root 'static_pages#home'

resources :requests 
end
```

The column in the db in the example is "done", and it is set as an integer.

I can provide more of my code is needed, but I'm trying to keep the question and sample simple and clear.

Comment: Could you add your controller action where you are handling the increment

Comment: You should add a `route` in the `routes.rb` file to call the controller function on `post` request.

Comment: your form submits to create or update action not incr_done

Comment: If `done` is an integer column in the database how is then `@request.done == "yes"` even possible? Where is the `yes` coming from? It feels to me like your example is missing some important information.

Comment: can you add your routes file?

Comment: @JohnBaker   here is the simple routes file.  Thanks as you guys are helping me at least brainstorm where I have the gaps in function.  For me I created that "incr_done" but honestly didn't even know how to call it with the form to even test it.  And yes the "yes" or "no" needs to be changed to 1 or 0 I think to match the radio button.

Comment: @pavittargill ^

Comment: @spickermann ^ thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes:

```
resources :requests do
  member { patch 'incr_done' }
end
```

View

```
<%= simple_form_for @request, url: incr_done_request_path do |f| %>

  <%= f.radio_button :done, 1 %>I am helping<br/><br/>
  <%= f.radio_button :done, -1 %>Maybe next time<br/><br/>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<%end%>
```

Controller

```
def incr_done
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  count = params[:request] && params[:request][:done].to_i

  if count.in? [-1,1]
    @request.update_attributes(done: @request.done + count)
  end

  # redirect path
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense and I can learn from that. I appreciate it.  Answer accepted and moving forward with the project.